# Is it possible to draw one line per ten lines in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot, sampling

I have data file like following:

```
#X1 y1 x2 y2 Number
123 567 798 900 1
788 900 87  89 2
....
```

and I draw my graph using following command

```
plot '~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
```

here is the result.

[image: Result Graph]

As you can see in above image, the result is to compressed, so I want to draw one line per ten lines which have same Number in data file.

**Edit1:**

I try @ewcz solution, as follow:

```
stat="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" # How should I define array as [gnuplot][2] didn't support it? 
plot "< awk '{if(( (stat[$5]++)%10==0 )) print}'~/Desktop/pointt.txt" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
```

but I get this error:

```
gnuplot> load "gnuplot.cmd"
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near 

gnuplot> plot "< awk '{if(( (stat[$5]++)%10==0 )) print}'~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
                                                                                                                                       ^
         "gnuplot.cmd", line 6: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

gnuplot> plot "< awk '{if(( (stat[$5]++)%10==0 )) print}'~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
                                                                                                                                              ^
         "gnuplot.cmd", line 6: x range is invalid
```

**Edit2:**

The solution:

```
 plot "< awk '{if((stat[$5]++)%10==0) print}' ~/Desktop/pointt.txt" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
```

Comment: These links use `every` option to draw line depend on the line number, how can I use this option in my case?

Comment: the `stat` array is internal to the invocation of `(g)awk`, the line `stat="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"` is not needed. Also, there should be a space in front of the `~` character so that `awk` can distinguish between the commands enclosed in apostrophes and the file being processed `~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt`

Comment: I still get an error :(

Comment: there should be a space after the apostrophe, i.e., `plot "< awk '{if(( (stat[$5]++)%10==0 )) print}' ~/Desktop/pointt.txt" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle`

Comment: I make mistake, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this, one has to use (most likely) some kind of preprocessing of the input. Fortunately, Gnuplot allows to plot a result of a command in a straightforward way. In your case, one could modify the plot command as:

```
plot "< gawk '{if((stat[$5]++)%10==0) print;}' ~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt" ...
```

Here, the id of the row (based on the fifth column) is stored in an array `stat`. If this id is divisible by `10`, the row is printed and thus consequently plotted (i.e., other input rows are discarded).

Comment: I get an error when try it, I have update the question depend on it